# MSIX default install to AppData, not ProgramFiles

Tags: windows-installer, msix

I found the [MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/package-conversion-command-line) tool to convert my MSI to a MSIX in order to submit to the Windows Store Win32 Desktop.

However my application was initially designed to install to AppData in order to be able to update itself automatically without administration privileges.

Is there a way to direct MSIX to install there? Or, should I not consider automatic updating anymore from my app and the update will be handled by the store?

Best,

Comment: Indeed, you should handle the updates through the Windows Store, no need to implement your own updater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [install path](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction.html#install-location) of an MSIX package cannot be customized. All the packages end up in the WindowsApps folder.

Since you want to publish your application in the store it is recommended you let the MS Store manage its updates, it is best you remove the code that handles the automatic updates.

By the way, the MSIX Packaging Tool was created by Microsoft for IT professionals that don't have access to the source code. Developers can either use the Windows Application Packaging Project project template (if they use Visual Studio) or other third-party tools, like Advanced Installer or Wix (from what I know there was a [Wix extension that can be used to build MSIX packages](https://www.firegiant.com/products/wix-expansion-pack/msix/)).

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*